# mod_rewrite Encoded Forward Slash Woes

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

While creating our automotive eCommerce store, we named a few products with Forward Slashes/Virgules in the name ("/") for example: `VOLKSWAGEN GOLF/GTI`. The eCommerce engine rewrites the URL for this product to be `GOLF%7B47%7DGTI`. We decided to go ahead and reword all of our products to use the world "AND" and instead of a forward slash/virgule.

We have a ton of links out there on the web and I always use mod_rewrite to ensure that these links still work after we change the naming convention for products. However, this one has got me stumped! Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
OLD URL: http://mystore.com/products/MK4-GOLF%7B47%7DGTI-KONI-STRUTS.html
NEW URL: http://mystore.com/products/MK4-GOLF-AND-GTI-KONI-STRUTS.html
```

The "MK4" part of the URL could be any of Mk1, Mk2, Mk3, Mk4, Mk5 or Mk6 and we also offer a variety of struts for each generation of the Golf/GTI. Therefore, I needed to write a rule that would replace Golf/GTI with GOLF-AND-GTI in the URL and carry over anything before or after the target string.

My current (incorrect) RewriteRule looks like this:

`RewriteRule ^products/(.*)-GOLF%7B47%7DGTI-(.*) http://www.mystore.com/products/$1-GOLF-AND-GTI-$2 [B,R,L]`

I've been pulling my hair out over this for the last couple hours and just can't seem to get a working rule in place. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Hi John, no need to flag your questions with "SOLVED": the fact you accepted the answer below, is a clear indication for future visitors that it solved your problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `%7B47%7D` decodes to `{47}` you can rewrite the URL as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)-GOLF\{47\}GTI-(.*) http://www.mystore.com/products/$1-GOLF-AND-GTI-$2 [B,R=301,L]
```

Also as your intention is to replace the old URLs with the new ones, you should use a 301 redirect instead of the default 302. This is the [recommended way](http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/301-versus-302.shtml) of handling permanent URL changes from SEO standpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked out perfectly! +1 and correct answer chosen! @Ketola

Side note: Since the rest of the URL contains '-' characters which are NOT encoded (e.g. products/MK1-GOLF-AND-GTI-KONI-STRUTS.html) I used the 'NE' flag instead of 'B' for the RewriteRule.

Comment: Using NE instead of B should be safe in that case, but you might as well leave it out entirely and let Apache escape characters as needed. Also as your intention is probably to get rid of the old URLs, you should use R=301 for a permanent redirect. This is optimal from SEO standpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input @Ketola, I've amended my redirects to use HTTP 301. I didn't know that this was beneficial for SEO but that does make a lot of sense! Thanks again so much for your advice!